# How to send a specific data in mjs file to API server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, class, server

I have 3 files that called `country.mjs`, `bridge.mjs` and `server.js` for an API. Each `js` files are related such as this:

---

- `country.mjs`: Has its own instance. Passes or receives datas from
  `bridge.mjs`.
- `bridge.mjs`: Receives or passes data to an instance. Getting invoked
  inside of `country.mjs`.
- `server.js`: API.

---

My goal is ***Cycling a Specific Data File to File***. I want to send a specific data called `this.pass` to the server, and gives back as a new data from it.

A problem is, when I try to send `this.pass` to API, the server gives an error `undefined` like this:

> undefined:1
>   export default class Bridge { ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0

I know a reason of the error is the server keeps trying to read the whole file, `bridge.mjs`.

I'd been searching the ways to get a specific peace of data inside of class syntax, but couldn't find any of infos.

Are there any proper solutions to send `this.pass` to the API?

Have look at the code blocks:

```
// country.mjs
import Bridge from './bridge.mjs';
class Country {
    constructor(name, capital, season, input) {
        this.name = name;
        this.capital = capital;
        this.season = season;
        this.input = input || new Bridge(this);
    }
}
let country = new Country('United State', 'New York', 'Autumn');

// bridge.mjs
export default class Bridge {
    constructor(output) {
        this.output = output;
        this.strings = JSON.stringify(this.output);
        this.pass = JSON.parse(this.strings); // Want to send this variable to an server.js.
        console.log(this.output, this.pass);
    }
}

// server.js
var express = require('express'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    buffer = fs.readFileSync('website/js/bridge.mjs'),
    storage = JSON.parse(buffer); // Gives an error
console.log(storage); // Gives an error

var app = express(),
    server = app.listen(3000, initialize);

function initialize() {
    console.log("Local Host Initialized.");
}

app.use(express.static('website'));
```

It's fine the data types are not `JSON`. Any types of data are okay if I can recruit, or retrieve the data using `forEach()`, `map()` or `reduce()`.

Thank you for listening.

Comment: So, bridge.mjs is a Javascript file, but you're trying to read it and parse it with `JSON.parse()`.  Javascript is NOT JSON - they are different formats.  So, you can't call `JSON.parse()` on a Javascript file.   If you want to run that Javascript in bridge.mjs, then use `import`.   There is no value for `this.pass` until somebody has loaded the code from that file and created a Bridge object.  Then, and only then, you could get the `.pass` property from that Bridge object.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks to comment, but what if I pass `this.pass` as an Array or an Object instead of JSON? Should I still use `import` keyword and create the specific instance of `Bridge`? Are there no ways to just get `this.pass` from the `bridge.mjs` and send it to the server?

Comment: You seem fairly confused about what a Javascript file is.  There is no `this.pass` in bridge.mjs.  There's some code that describes how a Bridge object works.  Once that code is loaded, someone can create a Bridge object and when they create it, they will pass the contructor a value that will get stored in the `.pass` property of that object.  But, until that code gets loaded and someone creates a Bridge object, there is no `.pass` property anywhere.

Comment: So, what you're asking doesn't seem to make any sense to me at all because you're asking for something that just doesn't work that way.  Perhaps you should back up a couple steps and explain what your overall problem is that you're trying to solve?

Comment: Please post text as text, not images of text.

Comment: @DaveNewton Edited the question.